# How to set dynamic edit text in a table row in android

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout, creation

I am creating an application consists of two drop down spinners(Example:Spinner A and Spinner B). By clicking button i want to get subtracted value from spinner A and B with that final subtracted value i want to create table rows with inside edit text fields.i had written some code. When i clicks the button no error was prompting but there was no table creation happening.This is what i did below when user clicks button please help me with this where i did them mistake

```
get_sheet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_get_sheet);
        get_sheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner_from_date_text = from_Date.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinner_from_month_text = from_month.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinner_from_year_text = from_year.getSelectedItem().toString();

                spinner_to_date_text = to_Date.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinner_to_month_text = to_month.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinner_to_year_text = to_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
                from_date.setText(spinner_from_date_text+"/"+spinner_from_month_text+"/"+spinner_from_year_text);
                to_date.setText(spinner_to_date_text+"/"+spinner_to_month_text+"/"+spinner_to_year_text);
                int value_from = Integer.valueOf(spinner_from_date_text);
                int value_to = Integer.valueOf(spinner_to_date_text);
                int result_table = value_to-value_from;
                sheet.setColumnStretchable(5, true);
                for(int i=0;i<result_table;i++)
                {
                        sheet_row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                        sheet_row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        for(int j=0 ;j<5;j++)
                        {
                            edt_text = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                            edt_text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            edt_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edt);
                        }
                        sheet_row.addView(edt_text);
                }

                sheet.addView(sheet_row);
```

Comment: put `sheet.addView(sheet_row);` inside outer for loop.

Comment: Ok buddy i will check it and get back to you@Tauqir

Comment: Nothing happening dude @Tauqir no table was displaying by clicking button.. :(